# Select Text and Wrap It In a Link w/ Java Script

Tags: javascript

I have text names such as John Smith, DDS, MD.  Actually 4 of them.  I want to wrap the name alone in a link. I'm able to get the innerHTML of the name and credentials, such as above, and then get just the name. My code seems to work but I can't seem to replace the text with a link. I can append the link but I don't want that.  Here's my code. And yes, this should be simple, but I'm still learning.

```
(function() {
    let link1 = document.querySelector(".elementor-post-author").innerHTML;
    let link2= link1.substr(0, link1.indexOf(','));

    let a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href="/somewhere";
    a.innerText = link2;
    
    link_name2.replace(link_name2,a);
})();
```

It's the last line I need help with. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is `link_name2` declared? Can we see some more code?

Comment: What is `link_name2`, a node(dom object)? If so you would use [`replaceWith(yourNodeElement)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith)

Comment: link_name2 removes the text after the first comma so John Smith, DDS, MD becomes John Smith. I want to put the link around the text John Smith, with the credentials afterwards.

Comment: link_name2 is a string (typeof()), but I don't know how to determine if its in the DOM.

Comment: And link_name2.replaceWith(a) is not a function in the console.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to append the `a` tag to the `document`, so you will need the parent element of where you want to add the newly created link.

```
const someDiv = document.getElementById('someDiv');
someDiv.appendChild(a);
```

Comment: Thanks. When I do that, which I did before, it adds a name with link (good) after the name and credentials (not good). I just want to replace the name with the same name but with a link.